# How to get HTML generated by a controller method as a HTML String

Tags: spring-boot

I have a method in a `@Controller` which generates a `ModelAndView` and rendered a JSP page. The resulting HTML is a report which is refreshed on-screen every few minutes.

I've now been asked to provide a snapshot of the report on the last day of each month. I feel the best way to do this without too much refactoring of the application is on the last day of each month, simulate a call to the method that generates the report, and capture the generated HTML so it can be rendered at any point in future.

I know how to setup a scheduled task within Spring Boot, but I'm struggling to figure out how to simulate a call to a controller and grab the response as a String that contains the HTML response from the report.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better if you save the data for that specific time (last day of each month) and render HTML for it when the user requests it?

Comment: Ideally that's what I would prefer to do, but it's much more time consuming as the visual report contains 4 different tables each with different types of data, so storing all of this data takes longer and currently not necessary for its use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you insist on the method you described, you can use the `RestTemplate` class

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
String url = "http://<path-to-your-report-view>";

ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.getForEntity(url, String.class);
if (response.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.OK) {
    String result = response.getBody();
    // ... Save the result
}
```